# Implementing a pipe functionality in shell. In C

Tags: c

In the provided code below, the redirection methods work, however i've been having trouble with getting the pipe function to work.

***This is how I'm viewing the flow of the code (at least for the pipe) and correct me if I'm wrong:*** When the array containing the users command (argv[]) is being traversed and checked for pipe declarations ("|"), for however many ("|") it detects, it will do that number of processes (processes++). It will then clear out the user command for future use, and go through the checks to continue the program.

I will also say I only have  processes declared and iterated once, and I wasn't sure if I return it or implement it somewhere else.

Here is what I have so far:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <signal.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>

 int main()
 {
   char *path,      //shell system path indicator
        *argv[20],  //user command
        buf[80], //will pass user command to argv
        n,          //user input
        *p;         //points to buffer

   int m,       // represents size
       status,  // checks if ant conditions violate the while loop
       inword,
       check,
       continu;

  while(1) //an infinite loop to keep the shell running
  {
    inword = 0; //set as false
    p = buf; // p represents buffer
    m = 0; //size of argv array
    continu = 0; //set as false

    printf("\nshhh> "); //display of shell prompt

    while ((n = getchar()) != '\n' || continu) //while user input is not end of line OR
    {
         if (n ==  ' ') // if input is a space
       {
            if (inword) // if 0
          {
            inword = 0; // remains 0
                *p++ = 0; //increment to next position in buffer[80]
          }
        }

          else if (n == '\n') //if user input == end of line
          continu = 0; // continue is 0 which breaks the while loop

        else if (n == '\\' && !inword) // if user input == '\\' and inword is not 0
          continu = 1; // continu is changed to 1 and you stay in while loop

          else
        {
             if (!inword)
           {
             inword = 1;
                 argv[m++] = p; //next iteration of user command contains buffer
                 *p++ = n; //next slot in buffer contains user input
             }
             else
                 *p++ = n; //next slot in buffer contains user input
          }
    }

    *p++ = 0; // next slot in buffer is 0
    argv[m] = 0; //clear user command

    if (strcmp(argv[0],"exit") == 0) //if user command is exit
       exit (0); //end program

int processes = 0,
    gate1,
    gate2,
    pipe_end[2],
    pipe_id;

    if (fork() == 0)// passing command to array
    {
      for(int iteratr = 0; argv[iteratr] != 0; iteratr++)
      {
        if(strcmp("|", argv[iteratr]) == 0)// pipe configuration
        {
          processes++;
          argv[iteratr] = 0; //empty array for next user command

          pipe(pipe_end);

          if (pipe(pipe_end)==-1) // Check for pipe functionality
            {
                perror("Pipe Failed");
                return 1;
            }

          pipe_id = fork();

          if (pipe_id < 0) //Check for fork functionality
          {
            printf("Fork failed");
            return 1;
          }
          else if(pipe_id == 0)//Child
          {
            close(1); //close stdout
            dup(pipe_end[1]); //copy stdout
            close(pipe_end[0]); //close read in
            close(pipe_end[1]); //close write out

            execvp(argv[0], argv); //execute "pre" read in
          }
          else //Parent
          {
            close(0); //close stdin
            dup(pipe_end[0]); //copy stdin
            close(pipe_end[0]); //close read in
            close(pipe_end[1]); //close write out
            execvp(argv[0], argv); //execute "sort" read in

          }

        }
        if(strcmp("<", argv[iteratr]) == 0)// Input redirect
        {
          gate1 = open("input.txt", O_RDONLY);
          close(0);
          dup(gate1);
          close(gate1);

          argv[iteratr] = 0;
                execvp(argv[0], argv);
        }
        if(strcmp(">", argv[iteratr]) == 0) // Output redirect
        {
          gate2 = creat("output.txt", 0750);
                close(1);
                dup(gate2);
                close(gate2);

                argv[iteratr] = 0;
                execvp(argv[0], argv);
        }
      }

      execvp(argv[0], argv);
      printf(" didn't exec \n ");
      check = wait(&status);
    }
    wait(&status); //check
  }
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: With `while ((n = getchar()) != '\n' || continu)` then `else if (n == '\n')` is not possible within the loop. You should also protect the array bounds in your `while` condition, e.g. `while (n < 80-1 && ((n = getchar()) != '\n' || continu))`. (commonly `argv[m] = 0;` should be `argv[m] = NULL;` -- and throughout the later pointer comparisons)  It will take a bit of time to trace your pipe opens/closes, but on first blush, it looks like with multiple fork you are short on file descriptors, will know more later.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin. I understand what you mean, however I am not to change any of that code. I should have included it in my description of the question. I am only allowed to make changes after  if (strcmp(argv[0],"exit") == 0).